# Determine the number of function $f$ : $\{1,2,3,4,5\}\to \{1,2,3,...,30\}$ with $f(i+1)\geq f(i)+2$

Tags: combinatorics

> Determine the number of function $f : \{1,2,3,4,5\}\to \{1,2,3,...,30\}$ with $f(i+1)\geq f(i)+2$

please show me the detail of explanation

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I just tried some counting. Nevertheless I couldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relate one such function with a corresponding sequence of dots and bars in a convenient fashion.

For example, the function $f$ such that $f(1)=2, f(2)=5, f(3)=9, \dots$ can be represented as $\star\mid \star\star\mid\star\star\star\mid\dots$

Rewritten with black numbers and red numbers instead... $1~\color{red}{2}~3~4~\color{red}{5}~6~7~8~\color{red}{9}~\dots$

It should hopefully be clear how to go from a function to such a sequence and vice versa.

---

Now... one more change to make in how we view the problem before we can really get started.  (*With the right phrasing you could probably have jumped straight here instead, but I think it is worth explaining the first step in my thought process too since it is a useful way to re-envision many problems*).

Let us describe such a sequence of stars and bars by the number of stars to the left of the first bar, the number of stars between the first and second bar, the number of stars between the second and third bar, and so on... so our running example could have been described by the six-tuple which begins $(1,2,3,\dots)$.  Let these numbers be called $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6$ respectively.

We can now translate the requirement that $f(i+1)\geq f(i)+2$ as instead the condition that $x_i\geq 1$ for each $i\in\{2,3,4,5\}$.

Now, take note of the fact that $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6$ adds up to the same amount for every function and you will have translated the problem away from a problem type you might not have been familiar with to a problem type you should be intimately familiar with.

> Find the number of integral solutions to the system $\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6 = 25\\ x_1\geq 0\\x_2\geq 1\\x_3\geq 1\\x_4\geq 1\\x_5\geq 1\\x_6\geq 0\end{cases}$

---

> We could have phrased things in a different way, going straight from describing the function as the sequence of 25 stars and 5 bars $\star\mid\star\star\mid\star\star\star\mid\dots$ as instead the sequence of 21 stars and 5 bars $\star\mid\star\mid\star\star\mid\dots$ where from each group of stars except the one at the very front and the very end we deleted one.

Answer (score 2):

Each such $f$ is a linear arrangement of $5$ black balls and $25$ white balls. In order to obtain an admissible $f$, take an *arbitrary* such arrangement with $5$ black balls and only $21$ white balls, there are ${26\choose 5}$ of them. Then insert an additional white ball immediately after the  first four black balls.